# Grafana fail metrics in dashboard

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

We have some incomplete data in our CPU panel, verifying that this happens only in a virtual machine and only in some metrics such as CPU, we updated the version of windows_exporter but did not solve. There has been no change to the query  is running on.

[image]

Query:

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(windows_cpu_time_total{mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100)
```

Grafana version:
v10.1.0

It was expected:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `$__rate_interval` instead of `2m`?

Comment: Yes, but it hasn't been resolved.

Comment: And does `windows_cpu_time_total{mode="idle"}` shows a continuous graph for that period of time?

Comment: The graph still appears with flaws in the metrics, even using the variable "rate interval", would you have any other suggestions for this case? Thank you.

Comment: It appears like you have lost data (maybe connectivity issues?). Check if query `windows_cpu_time_total{mode="idle"}` returns continuous graph.

Comment: When I run a query windows_cpu_time_total{mode="idle"} returns continuous graph.
If it were a connectivity problem would it not be correct to appear the problem in other panels such as memory?
It's continuous.
Thanks